# How to "Hover to an image and the video starts to play muted within the image area"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using wordpress and elementor, I want to have the effect that when users hover to an image, video starts to play muted within the image area, when the mouse hover out the video stop playing, and when we click on the image the video can play full screen. how to write the coding in javascript? I tried to ask chat gpt, but it's not working:

```
<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var myImage = document.getElementById("hoverimage");
var container = document.querySelector(".image-video-container");

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  myVideo.play();
});

container.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  myVideo.pause();
});
</script>
```

but above coding is not working

With the help of  @피케_ and @Madan Bhandari I made it. codes as below:

```
<div id="image-video-container" style="

position: relative;

height: 300px;

width: 400px;

overflow: hidden;

">

<img

id="hoverimage"

style="

position: relative;

height: 300px;

width: 400px;

overflow: hidden;

"

src="https://www.deliverystone.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/IMG_20230222_145146_1.jpg"

/>

<video style="

position: relative;

display: none;

object-fit: cover;

height: 100%;

width: 100%;

"

id="myVideo" loop="" muted="">

<source

src="https://www.deliverystone.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Aloha-Heja-He-BGM.mp4"

type="video/mp4"

/>

</video>

</div>

<script>

var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

var myImage = document.getElementById("hoverimage");

var container = document.getElementById("image-video-container");

container.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

if (container.requestFullscreen){ container.requestFullscreen();

myVideo.muted = false;}

else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen){

container.webkitRequestFullscreen();

myVideo.muted = false;}

else if (container.msRequestFullScreen){ container.msRequestFullScreen();

myVideo.muted = false; }

});

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {

if (!document.fullscreenElement) {

myVideo.muted = true;

}

myImage.style.display = "none";

myVideo.style.display = "block";

myVideo.currentTime = 0;

myVideo.play();

});

container.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {

myVideo.pause();

myImage.style.display = "block";

myVideo.style.display = "none";

});

</script>
```

Comment: I can’t see where you are hiding the image when you start the video playing and vice versa. How are you overlaying the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach

```
<script>
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  var myImage = document.getElementById("hoverimage");
  var container = document.getElementById("image-video-container");

  container.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    myImage.style.display = "none";
    myVideo.style.display = "block";
    myVideo.currentTime = 0;
    myVideo.play();
  });

  container.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    myVideo.pause();
    myImage.style.display = "block";
    myVideo.style.display = "none";
  });

  // this makes video full screen and play when clicked on parent container
  container.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (container.requestFullscreen) 
      container.requestFullscreen();
    else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen)
      container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (container.msRequestFullScreen) 
      container.msRequestFullScreen();
    myVideo.muted = false;
  });
</script>
```

Basically, you hide the image when `mouseover` on the parent div and show the video, and when `mouseout`, hide the video and show the image again.

Here is a [working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-galois-7s0014?file=/index.html:747-1341)

Comment: Much thanks for your quick help! I found it's working in your demo, I am now tring your approach, not working out yet in my page as I have limited knowledge about javascript... Will come back later! Much thanks!

Comment: I tried to send the codes to you thus you can help check, but too long to allow in comments, thus I edited the questions to include the codes copied from you. Please help check if you can find what is the problem!

Comment: `video appeared to play, but it's not the expected video` lol, obviously you'll have to replace the src link that I used in the in `source` tag in my example with your own video src link to show your expected video on hover.
`when the mouse is moved out, it's not coming back to the image` sorry I didn't understand why this could happen, as it is working fine in my codesandbox.

Comment: I found the problem now, before your coding, I put a hidden video above with same css id. thus the javascript mixed up with the css id. I did not realize that before.

Comment: now I need to set the video size to be same size, figuring how to set..

Comment: when I click on the image it starts to play muted, how to make it play with sound on?

Comment: Most browsers don't allow autoplay with `sound on` without permission, so it will be always muted at start, at least for new users.  Check this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) on autoplay.

Comment: @LeonardLiu you can add `myVideo.muted = false` at the end of click event function to play with sound on when clicked. I have updated the answer as well as my sandbox code.

Answer (score 0):

At first get the image and video with same dimension, so that they look fine at same size.

Set container sized based on image & video and set `overflow: hidden` to hide image/video going out of container.

```
#image-video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Additionally, you can use `object-fit: cover;` to make fill the container. something like this:

```
#image-video-container img {
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


#image-video-container video {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/9uo53t1g/18/).

Comment: I am using elementor, how to set in elementor?

Comment: set what ? this is css, just add this to your css, I mean by set is for the css style.

Comment: I want the video to fill the whole container, instead of just fit inside and leave blank area, how to set?

Comment: @LeonardLiu I have updated the answer with `object-fit: cover;` and `width`, `height` to `100%`

Comment: @LeonardLiu jsfiddle link is also updated

Comment: Awesome! now one more thing need to be fixed----now it's playing muted on click, how to make it play with sound on when clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253511/discussion-between-leonard-liu-and-madan-bhandari).